# how to achieve kafka-streams foreign key join

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-platform, confluent-cloud

I recently started working on **kafka-streams** and joins.
I’m just wondering is there any easy way to achieve foreign key join with multiple foreign keys in kafka-streams

**Employee topic**

```
{
"ID" : 1,
"Name" : "Jay",
"DepartmentIds": [2,3,4]
}
```

**Department topic**

```
{
"DepartmentId": 2,
"Name": "Computers"
}
{
"DepartmentId": 3,
"Name": "Electronics"
}
{
"DepartmentId": 4,
"Name": "Mechanical"
}
```

should be transformed into

**Joined Output**

```
{
"ID" : 1,
"Name" : "Jay",
"DepartmentIds": [2,3,4]
"Departments": [{
      "Department ID" : 2,
      "Name" : "Electronics"
   },
{
      "Department ID" : 3,
      "Name" : "Computers"
   },
{
      "Department ID" : 4,
      "Name" : "Mechanical"
   }]
}
```

Edit 1:

Tried solution 1 :

```
 KTable<String, EmployeeDepartments> employeeWithDepartments = employees.flatMapValues(value -> value.getDepartmentIds())
      .map((employeeId, departmentId) -> new KeyValue<>(departmentId, employeeId))
      .join(departments, (employeeId, department) -> {
        return new DepartmentWrapper(employeeId, department);
      }, Joined.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String(), departmentSerde))
      .groupBy((departmentId, departmentWrapper) -> departmentWrapper.getEmployeeId(), Grouped.with(Serdes.String(), departmentWrapperSerde))
      .aggregate(EmployeeDepartments::new, (employeeId, departmentWrapper, employeeDepartments) -> {
        employeeDepartments.setEmployeeId(employeeId);
        employeeDepartments.addDepartment(employeeWrapper.getDepartment());
        return employeeDepartments;
      }, Materialized.<String, employeeDepartments, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>
        as("EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENTS")
        .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
        .withValueSerde(employeeDepartmentSerde));
```

But above code aggregates all the departments across the events.
If the department got changed for any employee I still see the old departments in the aggregated state store.
I just want to see the latest departments of an employee always.

Tried solution 2 :

Below one works perfectly ! But I felt below one is not a efficient solution as it doesn't uses any kafka stream joins.

```
KStream<String, Employee> enrichedEmployeeObject = employees.transformValues(() -> new ValueTransformer<Employee, Employee>() {
      private ProcessorContext context;

      @Override
      public void init(ProcessorContext processorContext) {
        this.context = processorContext;
      }

      @Override
      public Employee transform(Employee inEmployee) {
        Set<Department> employeeDepartments = inEmployee.getDepartmentIds().stream().map(departmentId -> {
          ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<String, Department> departmentIdDepartmentMap = getTopologyStream()
            .store("DEPARTMENTS_TABLE",
              QueryableStoreTypes.<String, Department>keyValueStore());
          return departmentIdDepartmentMap.get(departmentId);
        }).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        inEmployee.setDepartments(employeeDepartments);
        return inEmployee;
      }

      @Override
      public void close() {
      }
    });
```

Comment: I guess you want to to a stream-table join? If so, you could define a GlobalKTable on the department topic, then use a stateful transformer that looks up all departments from the KTable's state store while processing the employee stream.

Comment: @user152468 Thanks for your reply. I tried above two solutions. Still I'm not completely satisfied with the approach. Could you please have a look above ?

Comment: Your second solution looks good to me. I don't think that it is inefficient. For each department of each employee you are doing a look up in the KTable by department-id. Since the KTable has an index on that id, this is quick. Also when using a join, you would have to do some kind of lookup.